# SQL count number of each actions performed on one object (using different tables)

Tags: sql, count, distinct

I have two tables, one is "Activity" table

```
UserId    ActionID    companyId
2971       1            334
2971       4            334
3343       2            124
4416       3            231
4416       3            231
```

The other is the "ActionType" table, which contains columns of:

```
ActionID    ActionTypeName
1           Download
2           Buy
3           View
4           Click
```

How should I construct my SQL to get each user's each distinct action,the name and their counts?

My desired result is something like:

```
UserId    ActionId    ActionTypeName  ActionCount
2971      1           Download        1
2971      4           Click           1
3343      2           Buy             1
4416      3           View            2
```

Really struggling with SQL.

Thanks for help

Comment: Awe come on you know you really want to have the action type names go across the tops as a pivot table would in excel :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
SELECT a.UserId, a.ActionId, b.ActionTypeName, COUNT(*) AS ActionCount
FROM Activity a
INNER JOIN ActionType b
ON a.ActionId=b.ActionId
GROUP BY a.UserId, a.ActionId, b.ActionTypeName
```

Answer (score 0):

Use group by clause to have your count like below:

```
  Select u.userid, a.actionid,a.actiontypename , count(actionid)
   from activity u
   inner join actiontype a
   on a.actionid = b.actionid
   group by u.userid, a.actionid,a.actiontypename
```